# Using "jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java" with Ruby

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I am using Jenkins/Hudson as my CI environment, and my tests use Cucumber-Ruby. I would like to use `jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java` with it. Any help is much appreciated (links, pointers etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install rake plugin for Jenkins.
2. Create a rake file with cucumber options
3. Make cucumber to produce `json` output report

And you should be done.  Check my similar question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492891/jenkins-rake-cucumber-json-report-empty

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber-jvm is a java-based tool where as Cucumber is a Ruby-based tool. You should find a better fit for your plugin such [Cucumber Test Result Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Test+Result+Plugin) or [Cucumber Reports Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin).

Comment: Not quite right. `It also works with ruby versions of cucumber...` - refer https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java